# Check if current user is available in distributed list which is stored in sharepoint people or groups column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, distributed

Distributed list(DL) is stored in sharepoint list people or groups columns. When user access a page, need to check whether current user is available in DL which is stored in sharepoint list.

Comment: Try to post this in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/